# Writing canonically a transitive action as quotient of a simply transitive action

Tags: gr.group-theory

Consider a finite group $G$ acting transitively on a finite set $Y$. Is it possible to find a finite set $P_Y$ and a finite group $\hat G$ acting on $P_Y$ such that the following hold?

- The action of $\hat G$ on $P_Y$ is regular, i.e. both free and transitive.
- There is a surjective map $\pi\colon P_Y \to Y$ and a surjective group homomorphism $\phi\colon \hat G \to G$ such that $\pi(g p) = \phi(g)\pi(p)$ for every $g \in \hat G$ and every $p \in P_Y$.
- The construction of $P_Y$, $\hat G$, $\pi$ and $\phi$ is 'canonical / functorial' in the sense that it does not rely for example on the a priori choice of an otherwise undistinguished element of $G$ or of $Y$.

Note that without the last condition the question would be trivial, since one could simply fix an arbitrary 'origin' $o \in Y$ and then take $P_Y = \hat G = G$, $\phi = id$ and $\pi(h) = ho$.

**Added in response to comments.** One way of formulating the functoriality condition which would certainly be good enough is as follows. Take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of pairs $(G,Y)$ as above with $G$ acting transitively on $Y$ and morphisms being the obvious ones (no surjectivity required). Then, one would like to have a functor $\mathcal{F}\colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Arr}(\mathcal{C})$ such that $\mathrm{cod}(\mathcal{F}(A)) = A$, $\mathrm{dom}(\mathcal{F}(A))$ is regular (in the sense of the first condition) and $\mathcal{F}(A)$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: To avoid arguments about what is or isn't canonical, do you mean functorial in the sense that you want an endofunctor $(G, Y) \mapsto (\hat G, P_Y)$ of the category of pairs of a group, and a set with a transitive action of that group?  Are the morphisms in that category all the obvious ones, or only the ones that are surjective on the sets, on the groups, or both, or something else?

Comment: Have you got any satisfactory answer for the action of the symmetric group of a finite set $X$ on $X$? (even for $|X|=3$?)

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I do mean functorial, I guess in pretty much any reasonable sense that is compatible with the first two properties. (The reason I am after this construction is precisely to construct a certain functor, but for a slightly more involved category that uses this as a building block.)

Comment: I don't mean to be picky; I just find it an interesting question, but don't want to spend time thinking of a construction (or a disproof) if it turns out that the way I interpret it isn't the way that you had in mind.  Is the category I suggest, with, say, surjective morphisms, a "reasonable sense that is compatible with the first two properties"?

Comment: A weak way of being functorial is to be functorial with respect to *isomorphisms* of pairs $(G,X)$ where $G$ is a group endowed with a transitive action on the set $X$.

Comment: @LSpice Fair enough ;-) I added a possible definition which would certainly be good enough for my purpose.

Comment: If one has such a "cover" $(\hat{G},P_Y)$ associated canonically to $(G,Y)$ and $N=\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$, then one can also associate canonically $(\hat{G}/N,N\backslash P_Y)$ which is also simply transitive. Hence, if I'm correct, we get the same with in addition $\phi$ an isomorphism.

Comment: ... Hence if $\mathrm{Aut}_G(G/H)$ does not embed into $G$ for some group $G$ and subgroup $H$, we probably get a contradiction to too strong functorial conditions. This is easy to find such examples. For instance, $G$ the quaternion group and $H$ its 2-element center. On the other hand, in this case there is a canonical cover, just it's not functorial with respect to automorphisms of the original action.

Comment: @YCor Thank you very much, this is very helpful. It sounds like I'll either have to exploit more of the specific structure of the problem this comes from or rely on a different construction.